# Combine different dataframe for calculating player score for particular match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How I can combine two different dataframes

```
 with open('C:\\Users\\dbda\\Downloads\\211028.yaml', 'r') as f:
 df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(yaml.load(f)) 
  #exclude columns of innings score 
  df2 = df[df.columns.difference(['innings'])]
```

I have created this another dataframe and for match wise reference i want to combine both of them since i will be dealing with 3000 matches. and the final_df dataframe.

code for Final_df is:

```
d = yaml.load(open('D:\\Dbda\\Project\\t20s\\211028.yaml'))
df_list = []
for i in d['innings']:
    df = pd.DataFrame(i[list(i.keys())[0]])

    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(
         pd.DataFrame(df.deliveries.tolist()).stack().tolist()
    ).assign(team=df.team)

    df_list.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

I want to combine these final_df and df2. and I have data of almost 3000 such files and perform operations on them.

Link of the files. almost 10-20 sample files.

and calculate the total score of a particular match. and find score of a particular player across all the matches he has played.

Comment: What is `df.columns.difference(['innings'])` doing here? From your previous question, there was no column called "innings"

Comment: Oh, I think I've understood. You want to add the meta-data columns to `final_df`? Do you want to add each meta-data as a separate column? Or what?

Comment: Keep in mind that this will lead to a LOT of data duplication, if you decide to have them as separate rows, so bear the fact in mind.

Comment: If you are planning to calculate scores across all matches, you don't really need to know what match the player played, do you? There is no other way of referring between the dataframes without separating your dataframes into smaller tables (think SQL!) and you can then merge tables as needed.

Comment: I would like to explain my problem statement; 

We have data of 3000 files. And we are planning to calculate score of all matches, Player wise, innings wise, based on ground we want to calculate the scores. Since we will be having different Yaml files we want to do above mentioned tasks. How we should approach that problem ?

Comment: Have you worked with SQL before? Have a table storing meta-data. Inside each `df_final`, just store a match id column, which helps you link to the meta-data table.

Comment: You can then do whatever you wish. I'm not going to solve your problem for you, but am helping you by pushing you in the right direction. The rest is up to you.